# Set mapkit to location with only a cityname

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, mapkit

I get data from an api. This data only contains the city name.
I would like to show the user a mapview of the city.

Does anyone know how to do this?
I found some things about the CLGeocoder api, could this help? or should i find a db with the lat & long for the europa's cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use forward geocoding with CLGeocoder using the geocodeAddressString method. More info at:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:

Or you could hit Google Maps services as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latitude and longitude of the address using Google Geocoding API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Newyork&key=PROVIDE_YOUR_API_KEY

Where API_KEY you have to register in developer.google.com

This will return a JSON format where you have parse through and get the nearest latitude and longitude.

For more details check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Assign the latitude and longitude into a CLLocationCoordinate2D and add the location in the Map using Markers/Annotations